# Display specific booking data below cart item name in Woocommerce Bookings

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, price, woocommerce-bookings

I'm using Woocommerce and Woocommerce Bookings for a villa booking website and I have a small issue I can't fix.

I'd like to add a field "Details" into my cart ([Cart Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQZn7.png)). This field will display the duration of the booking and also the price / night of each villa.

[image: Cart Details]

My villas have some resources with a specific block cost.

Regarding the duration value, I can display it by using this code bellow :

```
<?php

/*display_card_data();*/
$items = WC()->cart->get_cart();

foreach($items as $item) {
$duration = $item['booking']['duration'];
}
// displaying values for test
echo $duration. ' x Night Price' .$price ;

?>
```

I'm wondering how I can display the block cost in this field.

Please any help will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the following code *(but they can be many unit prices in WC Bookings)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'booking_details_after_name', 30, 3 );
function booking_details_after_name( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

    if ( isset( $cart_item['booking']['duration'] ) ){
        // Duration
        $duration   = $cart_item['booking']['duration'];

        // Price cost ( they can be many different )
        $base_cost  = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], '_wc_booking_cost', true );
        $block_cost = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], '_wc_booking_block_cost', true );

        // Output
        $product_name .= '<br><span class="booking-details">';
        $product_name .= $duration . __(" x Night Price ", "woocommerce")  . wc_price($base_cost);
        $product_name .= '</span>';
    }

    return $product_name;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

---

**Specific Update:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'booking_details_after_name', 30, 3 );
function booking_details_after_name( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

    if ( isset( $cart_item['booking']['duration'] ) ){
        // Duration
        $duration      = (int) $cart_item['booking']['_duration'];
        $resource_id   = $cart_item['booking']['_resource_id'];
        $start_time    = $cart_item['booking']['_start_date'];
        $end_time      = $cart_item['booking']['_end_date'];
        $loop_time     = (int) $start_time;
        $day           = 86400; // In seconds


        // Price cost ( they can be many different )
        $res_block_cost  = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], '_resource_block_costs', true );
        $booking_pricing = get_post_meta( $cart_item['product_id'], '_wc_booking_pricing', true );

        foreach ( $res_block_cost as $key => $value ){
            if( $key == $resource_id ){
                $bloc_cost = $value;
                break;
            }
        }

        $cost = array();

        foreach ( $booking_pricing as $key => $value ){
            $from = strtotime($value['from']); 
            $to   = strtotime($value['to']) + 86399;
            for( $i = 0; $i < $duration; $i++ ){
                if( $loop_time >= $from && $loop_time <= $to ){
                    $cost[] = $value['cost'];
                    $loop_time += $day;
                }
            }
        }

        $cost  = array_sum( $cost ) / $duration;

        // Output
        $product_name .= '<br><span class="booking-details">';
        $product_name .= $duration . __(" x Night Price ", "woocommerce") . wc_price($bloc_cost + $cost);
        $product_name .= '</span>';
    }

    return $product_name;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer Loic ! Your code is working properly and thank you for that, but the cost that I have to display comes from the resources of my villas. In fact, for example, I have a villa with 2, 3 and 4 bedrooms (so block cost changes in function of this parameter) and also, the price is increased depending the seasons (low, high and peak season). Do you have any idea how to get the total price / night regarding these parameters ? Thank you in advance, I'm very grateful.